# AEM Large number of modified child nodes

Tags: nodes, aem, jcr, jackrabbit-oak

My AEM Author instance crashes every night while authors work on the instance. This happen on a daily basis, but at any time during night (the authors team is in India, night for me at the time they work).

I have AEM in a server, behind an Apache instance with AEM Dispatcher in it. I tried to find patters around the HTTP calls that are made at the times of the crashes, and today I came across a weird warning message in logs:

```
11.05.2020 18:29:50.126 *WARN* [sling-oak-observation-2] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.DefaultSegmentWriter Large number of modified child nodes: 45000000 @ //oak:index/uuid/:index
```

This message is spread all over the place in logs, specially around those time when the instance goes down.

What does that message mean? Does the JCR repo really have a node with 45000000 childs?

Comment: This warning MAY or MAY NOT have anything to do with the server-crash. It complains about the UUID index. Could it be, that you create page-revisions in a batch mode? Search in your code for ".createRevision(" from the PageManager.

Comment: or you create a million versions and  this is a bug/overload in AEM's Version Purge. This should be part of the daily maintenance window. As this said, you should check, that the daily maintenance window is not in India's office hours (by default its 2-5 UTC => 7:30 - 10:30 India) - see Main menu -> Tools -> Operations -> Maintenance

Comment: Thanks. I'm on AEM 6.4, and went to /libs/granite/operations/content/maintenanceWindow.html/apps/settings/granite/operations/maintenance/granite_daily. The "Revision Clean Up" task is green, and as you said it is running at the same authors in India are working. But, this page also shows that this task runs only for a few minutes like less than 5. And slow requests are spread across 2-3 hours.

Comment: How often this instance is compacted? how many authors do work in parallel? Please review the slow query health check. I also would take a look at those indicators to get a hint of the underlying issue.

Comment: But the UUID index is strange. Maybe a misconfigured MSM? Do your pages have distinct UUID's (especially live-copies)? And stay they the same, after another rollout? Therefore check the OSGi config for "Day CQ WCM Rollout Manager". There should be jcr:* or jcr:uuid an excluded page-property. As last resort I would try to recreate the UUID index.

Comment: @ronnyfm the instance is compacted once per month. Not sure how many authors work in paralell

Comment: @AlexanderBerndt I'm kind new to AEM. What is MSM?

Comment: MSM = Multi-Site-Manager (blueprint, livecopy, rollout, ... - the Adobe guides in the internet give a good introduction). But if you are new to AEM, it is very hard to almost impossible to find the reason for strange server crashes. Even with support from Adobe and some really experienced AEM experts, such things can take weeks. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you all! I'm still having issues. This morning I had the chance to work with this team from India at the same time. The pattern is clear: when they send a bunch of pages for publishing, AEM takes a lot of CPU. And average response time from Apache start to build up. Do you think this may be due to live copies?

Answer (score 1):

The TarMK persistence layer cannot deal with a too large number of modifications to direct child nodes. This is what the warning message says:

```
11.05.2020 18:29:50.126 *WARN* [sling-oak-observation-2] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.segment.DefaultSegmentWriter Large number of modified child nodes: 45000000 @ //oak:index/uuid/:index
```

Unfortunately those modifications are in the UUID index, which is not under your direct control but managed by Oak internally.

You might be able to mitigate this shortcoming by reducing the pressure on the UUID index by reducing the number of version through version purge as Alexander Berndt also mentioned in his comment. Also version purging allows you to specify a retention policy. If your business case allows you can further reduce the number of versions by lowering retention time/count.

Further if you have many nodes of type `nt:resource` [consider switching](https://github.com/apache/jackrabbit-oak/blob/trunk/oak-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/jackrabbit/oak/builtin_nodetypes.cnd#L100-L108) to `oak:resource`. The former are referenceable and thus indexed in the UUID index, the latter are not.